# AddPrinterDriver fails with ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, printing

On a few computers a call to AddPrinterDriver fails with ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED. My program is ensured to run with administrator rights, and it copies the driver DLLs into C:\WINDOWS without any errors (access denied or other).

```
// structure for AddPrinterDriver
DRIVER_INFO_3 di3 = { 0 };
di3.cVersion = 3;
di3.pName = _T(MyAppPrinterName) _T(" Driver");
di3.pDefaultDataType = _T("");
// path to driver dll
FilePath file1(strDriverDirectory.c_str());
di3.pDriverPath = (LPTSTR) file1.Append(MyAppPrinterDriverDllFileName).ToString();
// path to driver ui dll
FilePath file2(strDriverDirectory.c_str());
di3.pConfigFile = (LPTSTR) file2.Append(MyAppPrinterUiDllFileName).ToString();
// path to license file
FilePath file3(strDriverDirectory.c_str());
di3.pDataFile = (LPTSTR) file3.Append(_T(MyAppPrinterName) _T(".dat")).ToString();

// add driver
bResult = AddPrinterDriver(NULL, 3, (LPBYTE) &di3);
StoreLastError(_T("AddPrinterDriver"));
if (!bResult)
    return FALSE;
```

This is my DrvPrinterEvent function:

```
BOOL DrvPrinterEvent(
                    LPWSTR  lpwstrPrinterName,
                    INT     iEvent,
                    DWORD   dwFlags,
                    LPARAM  lParam
                    )
{
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: That function requires that the caller posses the SeLoadDriverPrivilege. Administrators have this privilege but it is not enabled by default. You must call [AdjustTokenPrivileges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375202%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to adjust your process' privilege token.

Comment: He said his program is ensured to run with admin privileges, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @Carey: he almost certainly meant that the security token for the process is guaranteed to contain the Administrators group.  That means it will contain SeLoadDriverPrivilege, but as Amazed pointed out, it doesn't mean that it will be enabled.

Comment: What I meant is the exe that makes the call to AddPrinterDriver is launched by my Inno Setup installer, and Inno Setup would refuse to launch from a non-administrator account, it would display "You must be logged in as an administrator when installing this program."

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code.  So assuming you've verified that you have access to the DLLs and .dat file, the problem's not in the install logic.  Does your driver have a IPrintOemUI::PrinterEvent method or DrvPrinterEvent function that handles the PRINTER_EVENT_INITIALIZE event?  If so, check and make sure it's not returning false.  That will cause AddPrinterDriver to fail.

Comment: @satuon: have you tried enabling SeLoadDriverPrivilege yet?

Comment: @HarryJohnston:I've used AddPrinterDriver hundreds of times on every Windows version dating back to NT 3.51, and never have I had to enable SeLoadDriverPrivilege.  All that's required is admin privileges.  In fact, I just checked and it's enabled for the administrators group on two of my machines, and I haven't changed the security settings on either one.

Comment: @Carey Gregory starting with Windows Vista and the introduction of UAC, an administrator user's interactive session is given a filtered token that mimics a standard user. If you require a privilege which is restricted to administrators only you must explicitly enable it since all applications in the interactive session inherit the filtered token. Merely *being* an administrator is no longer sufficient.

Comment: @Legion: UAC isn't the issue here, the OP has already bypassed that.

Comment: @CareyGregory: when you say you checked, do you mean you called GetTokenInformation to get a TOKEN_PRIVILEGES structure and looked for the SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED flag?

Comment: @CareyGregory: if you've used AddPrinterDriver before without explicitly enabling the privilege then probably AddPrinterDriver enables it for you.  Some functions do.  I still think it's worth the OP trying, because since this behaviour isn't explicitly documented it might depend on context.

Comment: @CareyGregory: I've just checked on my Windows 7 machine and SeLoadDriverPrivilege is definitely not enabled by default in an administrator token.  (The only privileges that are enabled by default are SeChangeNotifyPrivilege, SeImpersonatePrivilege and SeCreateGlobalPrivilege.)

Comment: @Harry Johnston Agreed, UAC is not the issue since the filtered tokens will be used for an Admin's interactive session regardless of whether UAC is enabled or not. All UAC does is prompt the user before allowing the privilege to be enabled. The fact remains that the privilege required to perform this action must be explicitly enabled in NT6+.

Comment: @Legion: (a) UAC doesn't prompt the user to allow a privilege to be enabled, it prompts the user to allow a process to run with an unfiltered token; (b) if UAC is disabled the filtered tokens will not be used; (c) most privileges, and in particular SeLoadDriver, are not enabled by default even in older Windows versions; I've just checked this on a Windows 2003 machine and it is the same as in Windows 7.

Comment: @Harry Johnston I'll defer to your description of how UAC works, but you yourself just said that SeLoadDriver is not enabled by default. Given that fact, and the fact that the OP is receiving an Access Denied error, does it not stand to reason that at least *trying* to enable the one privilege listed as required for the function is a good place to start? If only to eliminate it as a culprit?

Comment: @Legion: I agree entirely.  See my previous comment to Carey.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Lots of responses here, but the bottom line is I've used this function in production code for many years in many applications and have never needed to fiddle with user privileges.  I think the privileges issue is a red herring unless the machines on which it fails have been altered.

Comment: @CareyGregory First, thanks for the interest, I've never seen such a big discussion. I've added DrvPrinterEvent code to the question. It's only a stub as you can see. This bug is extremely rare. I've received only 20-30 error reports with this error so far. It happens in XP, Vista, and Windows 7. Because it's so rare I assume the machines must have been tweaked. Maybe they've had something disabled with Group Policies.

Comment: @satuon: I suspect you're right about those machines having been tweaked.  Next time you see an example of it you should run the group policy editor and check.

Comment: @CareyGregory: thing is, it's like ten lines of code, what can it hurt to check?

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I'm not sure what you're asking.  You want me to check or satuon?

Comment: @CareyGregory: satuon.  See my answer.  It is likely that satuon is not in a position to actually go and visit a customer having this problem, so any diagnosis needs to be either done via a third party or via the code.  Code is more reliable. :-)

Comment: @satuon Please fold some of the details that you've revealed about the comments back into your question, as they are important to help others provide an answer for you.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Not really, eventually we abandoned the bug report. Without reproducing it there was no way of testing if we fixed anything.